# Some git equivalents for Plastic

Tags: plasticscm

What are the PlasticSCM equivalents to:

```
git clean -dxf
git clean -dx
```

I would like to remove every untracked file from my project tree, or every untracked, but not ignored, cloaked, or private, file from my project tree.

Comment: f you run "cm status --private", you should get a list of the private items not including ignored items. I guess you want to remove the private files (files stored in your workspace path but they are not under source control). In order to remove them: "cm status --private --short | xargs rm".

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent.  PlasticSCM has declined to implement this [feature](https://plasticscm.uservoice.com/forums/15467-general/suggestions/16803469-delete-all-unversioned-files)

You can find the thought process of how to solve this problem [here](https://forum.plasticscm.com/topic/20537-fully-cleaning-a-changeset/)

I implemented this for windows batch like this:

```
REM - Delete private files
for /f %%a in ('cm status --private --compact --short %~1') do (
   REM - IF IS DIRECTORY
   IF EXIST %%~sa\NUL ( rmdir /s /q "%%a" ) ^
   else ( del /s /q "%%a" )
)

REM - Delete ignored files
for /f %%a in ('cm status --ignored --cutignored --compact --short %~1') do (
   REM - IF IS DIRECTORY
   IF EXIST %%~sa\NUL ( rmdir /s /q "%%a" ) ^
   else ( del /s /q "%%a" )
)
```